# Map `Nothing` returned by `lookup` to default value

Tags: haskell

Say I have a list `l` of type `[(Int, Integer)]` such that the first element in every tuple is a (unique) index `i` in the range `0` to `n` and the second element in every tuple is an associated value `v`.

I want to "expand" this list into a list of `l'` type `[Integer]` with length `10` such that `l !! i == v` for all `(i,v)` in `l` and `l !! j == 0` if `(j,_)` is not in `l`.

I.e.: `[(1,10),(6,7)] => [0,10,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0]`

I'm not sure how to do this, I have tried:

```
map (\i -> lookup i l) [0..n]
```

That works except that the result is a list of Maybe's. An obvious solution is:

```
integerOrZero :: Maybe Integer -> Integer                                        
integerOrZero Nothing  = 0                                                       
integerOrZero (Just n) = n
```

And then:

```
map integerOrZero $ map (\i -> lookup i l) [0..n]
```

But I was wondering if there is a simpler way (maybe a one-liner) to write this "lookup with default". I guess `mayMaybe` doesn't work here.

Context: I'm trying to produce a histogram of values between `0` and `n` given a list of them, so overall I have thus far:

```
import Data.List (group, sort)

hist l = map integerOrZero $ map (\i -> lookup i l') [0..n]
  where l' = map (\x -> (head x, length x)) $ group $ sort l
```

I would like to write this as succinctly as possible using only functions from the `base` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `Data.Maybe.fromMaybe`, it is often forgotten.

[Data.Maybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe)

If you use `Data.Map.Strict`, there is a better choice. [findWithDefault](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:findWithDefault) must be what you want.